# Firefox Addon that reacts on click (left)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am just started to create firefox add on. My first try was to capture the users left click event and display an alert. but this isn't working:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    alert("blub");
}, false);
```

i also tried it wit "gBrowser". At the end i want to analyze the target element and if it matches some criteria i want to open a new tab with a link generated from data from the target tag.
for nearly all parts i found code snippets but first i need the simple click handling. besides this is there any syntax checking debugging tool. i am using Add-on Builder - i f i click on "test" for the code abov it says "add-on installed" but iam  unsure if it's syntactically correct.

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, mainly because your main.js does not have direct access to the window. This code example adds a click event listener to all open tabs:

```
require('sdk/page-mod').PageMod({
    include: ["*"],
    contentScript: 'window.addEventListener("click", function(e) { alert("blub"); }, false);',
    attachTo: ["existing", "top"]
});
```

I really recommend you look at the documentation for the add-on SDK to get started, there are some basic concepts you should learn so you don't get frustrated:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started

Comment: thanks! you are absolutly right - but my first try is always with sledgehammer. i also tried already to read the docs but there were no example that fit perfectly :-)

Comment: is it possible to call a defined function instead of an anonymous functions?